# Check if is_page(x) includes number from array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

Currently I'm checking the page_id of the current Page for an if/else statement.

```
<?php if (is_page(467) || is_page(110) || is_page(54) || is_page(82) || is_page(106) || is_page(35) || is_page(84) || is_page(76) || is_page(100) || is_page(68) || is_page(92) || is_page(440) ): ?>
```

How can I create an array of those id's and check them in a single `is_page()`?

The Array would be:

```
[467, 110, 54, 82, 106, 35, 84, 76, 100, 68, 92, 440]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_PAGE_Page) you can pass `array` to `is_page()` function.

> is_page( array( 42, 54, 6 ) )
>
> Returns true when the Pages displayed is either post ID = 42, or post ID = 54, or post ID = 6.

```
<?php $allowedPages = array(467, 110, 54, 82, 106, 35, 84, 76, 100, 68, 92, 440); ?>
<?php if (is_page($allowedPages)): ?>
```

Comment: I'm getting a `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' on line 20`

Comment: @TheMiniJohn Oh, I thought you are using PHP 5.4+. Use `array()` instead of `[]`. Answer updated.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, should have clarified. Everything works perfectly. Thanks !